# Flutter not able to find virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-virtual-device

I have a problem with Flutter. I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1 on Ubuntu 18.04. I am not able to make it find my virtual devices.

When I run `flutter doctor`, the following output is shown:

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v0.11.10-pre.3, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[!] Connected device

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

When I run `flutter emulators` it finds the device:

```
$ flutter emulators
1 available emulator:

Nexus_5X_API_28 • Nexus 5X • Google • Nexus 5X API 28

To run an emulator, run 'flutter emulators --launch <emulator id>'.
To create a new emulator, run 'flutter emulators --create [--name xyz]'.
```

I can then run `flutter emulators --launch Nexus_5X_API_28` to start the emulator. It opens as expected.

When I run `flutter doctor` again, it is still not able to find the device:

```
    $ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v0.11.10-pre.3, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[!] Connected device

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

The same thing happens when I try to start the emulator from the device dropdown pane. I can select `Open Android Emulator: Nexus 5X API 28`, and it will open the device but still show `<No Devices>` after the emulator has started.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you notice the `[!] Connected device` and `! Doctor found issues in 1 category.`? please run `flutter doctor -v` to see the details of the issue and then update you question, ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @Feu on the question above, I found out that the problem was the following:

I had to do some setup on the virtual device after unlocking it. I didn't notice this, but running `flutter doctor -v` made it all clear:

```
[!] Connected device
• Device emulator-5554 is not authorized.
  You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.
```